# Workflow with variables

Tags: workflow

I'm just getting started with workflows and need a little help. I have a list (Project tracker) that has the following fields: manager, project manager, resource 1, resource 2).

I need help figuring out how to write the SP 2013 workflow so that if there is a name in one of these four fields.. the item is copied to another list (resource tracker)..but, if there is no name it is not copied over. In addition, if the name on the project tracker changes, it's updated on the resource tracker.

I'm a beginner so a lot of guidance is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly basic workflow you are looking for. There are many guides to the absolute basics online. In terms of creating the workflow here is a guide.

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b?CorrelationId=c31cb36f-194b-4030-880b-1c3f0e1df12c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

In regards to your specific issue, for simplicity, you could make two separate workflows to handle the two things you want to do, one workflow that is run when new items are created and checks the four fields for names and will create new items accordingly, and another workflow which is only run on an item edit that will update the other item for you.

Example of conditional: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4yyZZEJtnmc/UWEZlZwuTuI/AAAAAAAAA3A/pMbOSWXTteU/s1600/State+Machine.png

In workflow one, what you will want to do is use the **Condition** "If any value equals value".  Once you put this conditional in you will check if the field contains the information you are looking for. Do this for each fields. If this condition that there are names in any of the fields, use the **Create List Item** action to copy the item to another list.

In workflow two, you will want to use the **Update List Item** action, which you can use to update the item with its new name.  You can see in this picture on the workflow's page within Sharepoint Designer how you can set your workflow to run on new items or edits.

http://blogs.salmanghani.info/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/243.jpg